# Does "user" interact with "hardware" or "graphical interface"?

Tags: x11, display-server

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server,

- does "graphical interface" mean clients of display server?
- shouldn't "user" interact with "hardware" instead of "graphical interface"? If not, how does a user interact directly with "graphical interface"?

Thank.

[image]

Comment: That's just a diagram, don't overthink the problem. It shows which layer is "closer" to the user. In reality user interacts only with mouse, keyboard and display monitor.

Comment: That's a dumb diagram. But isn't wikipedia editable? Not only the diagrams, but the whole article is in need of some love ;-)

Comment: Don't try to unserstand computer system using a simple diagram. There're tons of details can't be fit into diagram.

Answer (score 0):

> does "graphical interface" mean clients of display server?

Not necessarily

> shouldn't "user" interact with "hardware" instead of "graphical interface"?

Just degrees of separation; shouldn't the user interact with nurons or the atomic electric fields of the hardware.